# Computing Cech cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I have a structure sheaf on $\mathbb C^n \smallsetminus \{0\}$ and the open covering $U_i = \mathbb C^n \smallsetminus \{(x_1,...,x_n) \mid x_i=0\}$.
I want to compute Cech cohomology for this covering, but I have no idea how to do this.

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried to write the complex ?

Comment: @Roland yes, but I don't know how it can help:(

Comment: Well this is an explicit computation, write down the complex and the differentials, compute kernels and images and then homologies.

Comment: @Roland unfortunately, I don't understand how I can compute, for example, kernels, because I don't know how I can explicitly see what elements go to zero.